# Listing sales with a matching quantity

Tags: c++

Ive been sitting here for the past 20 minutes trying to make this simple/tiny function more 'readable' and 'clean'. Am I overthinking this or am I missing some major tips that could help me out?

```
string findSameSales (int numSold, int salesArray[], string namesArray[])
 {
  string ssList = " ";
  for (int counter = 0; counter <= NUM_OF_POS; counter++)
    {
      if (numSold == salesArray[counter])
        {
         if (ssList == " ")
           ssList = namesArray[counter];
         else
           ssList += (", " + namesArray[counter]);
        }
      else;
    }

  return ssList;
 }
```

Comment: You could drop `else;`

Comment: You could drop the magic value of `" "` and just say something like `if (ssList.empty()) ssList = ...`

Comment: you could drop the use of arrays. And I'd strongly recommend the use of braces around even single statements.

Comment: @john Im using the " " so that the format ends up looking nice when the program is run. The namesArray has the list of products with a space already in them. The " " helps me output like this ": Mild , Hot , Zesty ". Kinda want that extra space at the start of the string

Comment: @MahavirBhakta If that is what you meant then that is different from the code you posted. Try `ssList += namesArray[counter];` instead.

Comment: First define _readable_, otherwise this question is not answerable.

Comment: I would not set `ssList` to a space, I would leave it empty and check for that instead. We can't see the rest of your code, but `counter <= NUM_OF_POS` is generally an out of range condition. You probably want just `<` instead. I would also use vectors that know their own size over plain arrays and magic defines or consts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that's just subjective and there are many different formatting guidelines (working within a specific company or OSS project just follow theirs), but I personally would format that code like this for better readability and simplification of logic:

```
string findSameSales (int numSold, const int salesArray[], const string namesArray[]) {
    string ssList = " ";
    for (int counter = 0; counter <= NUM_OF_POS; counter++) {
        if (numSold == salesArray[counter]) {
            if (ssList == " ") {
                ssList = namesArray[counter];
            }
            else {
                ssList += (", " + namesArray[counter]);
            }
        }
    }
    return ssList;
}
```

In any case just drop `else` branches which do nothing, that is just confusing  noise thrown to a reader.

Also always stick to braces `{}` within conditional code blocks. There have too many mediocre maintainers been seen getting these wrong, and try to add an additional statement line without introducing braces as necessary.

Comment: `salesArray` and `namesArray` should be `const` for extra readablilty.

Comment: @john Good point, but might need more explanation.

Comment: @Downvoter I mentioned that the question is subjective, and of course voted to close it as such. Nevertheless, that doesn't give you a reason to downvote a correct answer. I don't mind if that question gets deleted after closing, but answers go to answers, and comments go into comments.

Comment: are we sure `counter <= NUM_OF_POS` shouldn't be `counter < NUM_OF_POS` ?

Answer (score 2):

How about using `std::accumulate()`:

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YpkSN3)

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

const int NUM_OF_POS = 10;

std::string findSameSales (int numSold, const int salesArray[], const std::string namesArray[]) 
{
    int index = -1;
    return std::accumulate(salesArray, salesArray + NUM_OF_POS, std::string(" "), [numSold, namesArray, &index](std::string sales, int sold) { index++; return sold == numSold ? sales + " , " + namesArray[index] : sales; });
}
```

Alternative on more lines:

```
std::string findSameSales (int numSold, const int salesArray[], const std::string namesArray[]) 
{
    int index = -1;
    auto accumulator = [numSold, namesArray, &index](std::string sales, int sold) 
    { 
        index++; 
        return sold == numSold ? sales + " , " + namesArray[index] : sales; 
    }
    return std::accumulate(salesArray, salesArray + NUM_OF_POS, std::string(" "), accumulator);
}
```

I really believe you should use STL algorithms for these kinds of things. Only roll your own loop etc. when you cannot use them. But this for example is almost the same as in the C++ reference docs so almost a "model case".

Comment: I personally find the one long line style less readable, but that's just me.

Comment: @RetiredNinja You can always make the lambda a variable or wrap the line however you like. I find it more readable because the intent is quite clear and details are not all that relevant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts on different aspects.

1. early exit could help to get rid of one `if`. The more code is nested the harder to read:

   ```
   for (int counter = 0; counter <= NUM_OF_POS; counter++) {
       if (numSold != salesArray[counter]) continue;
       // ....
   ```
2. You actually do here 2 different things: filtering array and getting formatted string from filtering's result. Making function to have single purpose would increase its readability and reusability
3. have you looked into libraries you used for existing filtering features? say [std::copy_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/) or something like that. Standard calls are much more *readable* since they are already known for reader.

Comment: @jww you are right. fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would generally do, but it is purely subjective.

I assume the `<=` is correct although generally it would not be.

```
#include <string>
const int NUM_OF_POS = 1;

std::string findSameSales(int numSold, int salesArray[], std::string namesArray[])
{
    std::string ret;
    for (int counter = 0; counter <= NUM_OF_POS; ++counter)
    {
        if (numSold == salesArray[counter])
        {
            ret += ret.empty() ? " " : ", ";
            ret += namesArray[counter];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```